# Error: Task 'UpdateLocationOnBackground' not found for app ID - REACT NATIVE EXPO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, taskmanager

I'm new to react native expo and I'm struggling to use task manager in the background, what I'm trying to show on the map is a marker and in the foreground, it works fine, but I want the marker coordinates to be updated even in the background. With TaskManager, I'm facing this error and I don't know if there are other ways that may be more effective.
The error I get is as below.

**Error: Task 'UpdateLocationOnBackground' not found for app  ID**. I checked on the internet but didn't find any clue how to solve this.
Below is my code! If someone knows how to solve this, or has any other suggestions please share :)

```
 const requestPermissions = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('UpdateLocationOnBackground', {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      });
    }
  };


useEffect(() => {
    console.log('USE EFFECT CALLED');
    console.log('--------------------------------', appStateVisible);
    if (!appStateVisible === 'active') {
      setBackgroundOn(true);
      requestPermissions()
      const permmisionOn = TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync('UpdateLocationOnBackground');
      console.log('BackgroundTask is ON!', permmisionOn)
    } else if (appStateVisible === 'active') {
      setBackgroundOn(false);
      const permmisionOff = TaskManager.unregisterTaskAsync('UpdateLocationOnBackground');
      console.log('BackgroundTask is OFF!', permmisionOff);
      console.log('USE EFFECT Ended!');
      return;
    }
  }, []);
```

// GLOBAL SCOPE

```
TaskManager.defineTask('UpdateLocationOnBackground', async ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
  try {
    if (locations) {
      let backgroundCoords;
      const { latitude, longitude } = locations[0].coords;
      backgroundCoords = { latitude, longitude };
      console.log('IT WORKS IN BACKGROUND', backgroundCoords);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error from BackgroundTask: ', error);
  }
});
```